# extracting string from JSON file using Typescript

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently trying to extract data from a JSON object. After parsing it and trying to access the data in it. I am able to successfully get the numerical and boolean values of the JSON object but the string objects only return a blank string. Is there something i am missing? I assume the code is right as i get the other values just fine. I can post the code if needed to help.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
//getting the object layer of the TILED map in a for loop
for (var layeridX = 0; layeridX < TILEDATA_CACHE[index].layers.length; layeridX++) {
            if (TILEDATA_CACHE[index].layers[layeridX].type !== "objectgroup") continue;
            var tileObjects = TILEDATA_CACHE[index].layers[layeridX].objects;

           var obj = {
                "name": "",
                "width": 0,
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0
            };
...other irrelevant code here...

    obj.name = tileObjects[x].name; //PROBLEM, it gives a blank string
    obj.x = tileObjects[x].x; //works fine, gives the value in the json
}
```

and the specific part of the json i am trying to pull is

```
"objects":[
            {
             "gid":21,
             "height":0,
             "name":"object1",
             "properties":
                {
                 "exit":"true"
                },
             "type":"1",
             "visible":true,
             "width":0,
             "x":63,
             "y":57
            }, 
            {
             "gid":22,
             "height":0,
             "name":"object2",
             "properties":
                {

                },
             "type":"2",
             "visible":true,
             "width":0,
             "x":158,
             "y":95
            }, 
            {
             "gid":16,
             "height":0,
             "name":"object3",
             "properties":
                {

                },
             "type":"3",
             "visible":true,
             "width":0,
             "x":10,
             "y":189
            }, 
            {
             "gid":17,
             "height":0,
             "name":"object4",
             "properties":
                {

                },
             "type":"4",
             "visible":true,
             "width":0,
             "x":156,
             "y":227
            }],
     "opacity":1,
     "type":"objectgroup",
     "visible":true,
     "width":20,
     "x":0,
     "y":0
    }],
```

Comment: Please include some code.

Comment: I edited the post with the relevant code.